# I am creating a Website using mariadb and php7 and need direction

Tags: php, sql, variables, mariadb

I am trying to figure out how to create variables to use throughout the page from $row.  For example:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';?>

<?php
    //Pull ALL data from database

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM barbarian_database WHERE product_id = '2';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultcheck > 0){
                While ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                }
            }
        $productid = $row['product_id'];
        $model = $row['model_name'];
        $model = $row['model_name'];


?>
```

I am getting an error for the variables:

```
    $productid = $row['product_id'];
    $model = $row['model_name'];
    $model = $row['model_name'];
```

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\newbarb.com\tester.php on line 15
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\newbarb.com\tester.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\newbarb.com\tester.php on line 17

This used to work in older versions of php but for some reason in php7 it does not.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using a loop if you are only expecting 1 row?

Comment: And why you're trying to get `$row` indexes outside the loop? In case of null result at output of your query it will raise your errors.

Comment: _“This used to work in older versions of php”_ - no, it didn’t. Not the code you have shown. Not “worked” as in produced any meaningful output. The `while` loop ends when `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns `false`. So `$row` will either be false after, or completely undefined in case the condition the loop is wrapped in wasn’t true. So there is no way you ever got any meaningful values for `$row['product_id']` etc. after the while loop - not with _that_ code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

//Pull ALL data from database

$sql = "SELECT * FROM barbarian_database WHERE product_id = '2'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultcheck > 0){
            while ($row = $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo $row['product_id'];
                        echo $row['model_name'];
                        echo $row['model_name'];
            }
        }
```

?>

In your example you don't need variables because you print but you will need variables if you add something. echo is for display and your error is because you weren't in the loop